# Recovery of APFS volume on external disk accidentally erased by Time Machine configuration on macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, hard-drive, time-machine, data-recovery

Long story short: adding an APFS volume located on an USB disk to Catalina TimeMachine configuration leaded to start erasing not only the volume but the whole disk. I disconnected the disk during erase operation and, since I got no errors mounting read only later, I'm searching for a solution to recover the lost volume(s) list and/or contents.

---

TL;DR: I have a multi volume APFS USB hard disk which I use for various backups (a Time Machine volume for my MacBook16 with Ventura, another one for backing up my iMac with Monterey and other volumes used as external file storage).

I wanted to backup my old MacBook13 which is on Catalina so I made another volume named "TMMacBook13" on this disk.

I attached the USB disk to MacBook13 with macOS Catalina and started Time Machine configuration trying to use "TMMacBook13" volume as backup destination: at this point I got a dialog saying that "TMMacBook13" volume needed to be "initialized" (translated from italian "inizializzato", I think original english dialog could be "needs to be erased").

Since the dialog was referring to the "TMMacBook13" volume, I launched Disk Utility to monitor what will happen and I proceeded with "initialization". At the very moment I saw a volume disappear from Disk Utility I understood that it was erasing the whole disk and not only the volume so I immediately disconnected the USB cable.

Later I mounted this drive in read only mode on Ventura using Disk Arbitrator to get read lony mounts and I saw that at least a volume was missing, good luck that during mount I got no warnings regarding possible disk corruption.

Now I know I lost at least a volume but, since I didn't write anything on it after the problem occurred, can someone tell me:

1. I'm right if I'm assuming that other volumes' contents are fine since I haven't got warnings during later mount
2. if there is a way to get the original volume list so I can check how much volumes I lost
3. if there is a way to get back / recover the original volumes

Is there any software / way to get at least point 2, even manually with an hex editor or a forensic kit (even Linux based)? I'm not using the file based undelete tools because one of this volumes was a copy of my system disk made with Carbon Copy Cloner, so it will find thousands and thousands of files of various types.